# Does enabling ACLs have an effect on performance?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, performance, acl

I'm looking at a web application that needs ACLs enabled. Are there any benchmarks or other documents to show what potential impact ACL does{n't} have when the file system is under heavy load?

Also, does it matter what filesystem you use with ACLs?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with a similar question and found this [Usenix article](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher_html/main.html) which has a section **EA and ACL Performance** discussing a comparison of time taken with and without ACLs. Also compares this for different file systems, which shows interestingly that XFS-512(inode size) and JFS do not cause a performance impact.

So definitely the ACLs cause a performance degradation depending on the file system type but it also depends on your production load, server resource and how much overhead is acceptable.